# How to invite friends in Facebook using social framework

Tags: facebook, ios6, social-framework, facebook-invite

I'm developing social media app with Facebook.
And my application is supporting both iOS 5 and iOS 6 and I want to use native facebook for inviting friends.

In iOS 5 its working fine using graph api. And in iOS 6 new features added by apple that we can use Facebook natively as twitter. So we don't need to login from our app it will take credential from setting screen of iphone in iOS 6.

So for this I have to use social framework as we are using in twitter.
I successful in use of native dialog for Facebook image share and post as it looks like in twitter.

Now I want to invite friends in Facebook using native dialog ( Social framework).

And I have no idea how to invite friends in iOS6 using social framework.

I search a lot but not able to find any solution even I dont know is it possible or not ?

If anyone have got sample project or good idea for this,please notice to me.

I hope you understand my problem...

if not please tell me..

Comment: Hello,
Same question here.
I would like to send invitations in Facebook with Social Framework.

I can do it with the Framework provide by Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/

But with iOS 6 and the Social Framework how to invite friends with the native Facebook integration?

Thanks.

Comment: Benoit: did you find the answer to your query?  I am also looking for a solution to this. Thanks!